# Magento theme name require

Tags: theme

I need a similer Magento theme of this site

www.elan.pk

Can you please help me to find out.

Comment: why don't you ask the store owners directly?

Comment: I asked him but he don't want to tell

Comment: `app/design/frontend/elan/default` you theme path.

Comment: Go to `System > Configuration > Design > Package > Theme`  , under Default textfield you can see theme name.

Answer (score 1):

The theme is named `elan`. So judging by the name of the website I would say is custom made.